# how can i get what version is my flux via CMD?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have installed `react-native-router-flux` for my learning project. i need to know what is the exact version of that, so on my project folder I used `react-native-router-flux -version` but it didn't work. how can i get what version is that via CMD?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `npm` as a package manager, you can type `npm list react-native-router-flux`. Similarly, if you are using `yarn` you can type `yarn list react-native-router-flux`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yarn outdated` or `npm outdated` to see your package that are out of date. if a package is not in this list it means that you are using the last version of that package.
By using `yarn outdated` you can see the current version, wanted version and the latest version of each package.